# query collection for multiple fields with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have an `IEnumerable<Videos>` object that I want to search for a single searchterm in multiple fields of the IEnumerable, inlcuding related data (Tags).

The Video, VideoTags and Tag object looks like this

```
public class Video
{
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Description {get; set; }
   public ICollection<VideoTags> VideoTags {get; set;}
}

public class VideoTags
{
   public Guid VideoId {get; set; }
   public Video Video {get; set; }

   public Guid TagId{get; set;}
   public Tag Tag {get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
   public Guid Id {get; set; }
   public string TagName {get; set;}
}
```

How can I efficiently search for a single searchterm in the fields Name, Description and TagName, if any of them contains the searchTerm, and then return a `List<Tuple<string, string, string>>`.

The code below doesn't work

```
videos = videos.Where(v => v.Name.Contains(searchTerm) ||
                v.Description.Contains(searchTerm) ||
                v.VideoTags.Where(t => t.Tag.TagName.Contains(searchTerm))
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: OPerator || cannot be applied to operand of type bool and IEnumerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Select` clause to return the `Tuple`. Also `Any` is used to validate if video tags contains the search term for TagName.

```
videos = videos.Where(v => v.Name.Contains(searchTerm) ||
                v.Description.Contains(searchTerm) ||
                v.VideoTags.Any(t => t.Tag.TagName.Contains(searchTerm)))
                .Select(v => new Tuple<string, string, string>(v.Name, v.Description, v.VideoTags.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Tag.TagName.Contains(searchTerm))));
```

The `VideoTags` is not a collection so you can Check the search term in `TagName` by accessing the property directly.

Comment: You should include VideoTags.

Comment: In Select it throw an exception.

Comment: Thnx for your response, VideoTags is a ICollection, however. I've updated my post with it.

Comment: Can you please post the exception?

Comment: @CMorgan - I've updated the answer to include VideoTags as collection. `Any` is used to check the condition and `FirstOrDefault` is used to get the first value.

Comment: Thnx, I'm trying it. Will get back to let you know